# Change Index of Two Python Lists Simultaneously

Tags: python, indexing

i'm using python 3, and have two lists that are related by their indices, but have separate values.

```
scans = [400,405]
points = [101,201]
```

So, for example, scan 400 has 101 points, and scan 405 has 201 points.

i'm trying to construct a set of filenames (i.e. strings) for each scan that looks like:

```
2idd_flyXMAP_0400_0.nc
2idd_flyXMAP_0400_1.nc
2idd_flyXMAP_0400_2.nc
...
2idd_flyXMAP_0400_98.nc
2idd_flyXMAP_0400_99.nc
2idd_flyXMAP_0400_100.nc
```

and

```
2idd_flyXMAP_0405_0.nc
2idd_flyXMAP_0405_1.nc
2idd_flyXMAP_0405_2.nc
...
2idd_flyXMAP_0405_199.nc
2idd_flyXMAP_0405_200.nc
```

Notice scan 405 will have more files associated with it. i got close with the the following code, but the nature of the nested for loop has me iterating too many times, and generating unwanted strings (i.e. a set for scan 400 containing 200 points, and a set for scan 405 containing 100 points, both are unnecessary).

```
scans = [400,405]
points = [101,201]

for scan in scans:
    pre_f = '2idd_flyXMAP_0' + str(scan) + '_'
    for point in points:
      endfile = list(range(point))  #this seems to be where the problem is; i generate four sets of lists here because i have two elements in two lists
      for point in endfile:
          f = pre_f  + str(point) + '.nc'
          print(f)
```

i may be setting this up inaccurately, but what i'd like to do in this case is change the index of both the `scan` for loop and the first `point` for loop once the first `point` for loop completes. i'm not sure how to accomplish this, but i think that should resolve my issue.

of course i'm open to separate, simpler approaches and thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
for point, scan in zip(points, scans):
   for p in range(point):
      print("2idd_flyXMAP_0{a}_{b}.nc".format(a=scan, b=p))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip):

```
scans = [400, 405]
points = [5, 6]

for scan, point in zip(scans, points):
    pre_f = '2idd_flyXMAP_0' + str(scan) + '_'
    for p in range(point):
        f = pre_f + str(p) + '.nc'
        print(f)
```

**OUtput**

```
2idd_flyXMAP_0400_0.nc
2idd_flyXMAP_0400_1.nc
2idd_flyXMAP_0400_2.nc
2idd_flyXMAP_0400_3.nc
2idd_flyXMAP_0400_4.nc
2idd_flyXMAP_0405_0.nc
2idd_flyXMAP_0405_1.nc
2idd_flyXMAP_0405_2.nc
2idd_flyXMAP_0405_3.nc
2idd_flyXMAP_0405_4.nc
2idd_flyXMAP_0405_5.nc
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

```
for index, scan in enumerate(scans)
    for point in range(points[index])
        output = "{i}: {s}-{p}".format(i=index, s=scan, p=point)
        print(output)
```